# Run Appium test directly without closing the app after first test case

Tags: python, android, unit-testing, automation, appium

I want to run the appium test case in 1 flow from login (case_01) into add task (case_02). But it always closes the app so I cannot do the add task (case_02) because it needs to login (case_01) first. I'm using ToDoIst. Here are my test unit file, login file and add task file.

TestUnit.py

```
from AppiumFramework.Pages.AddTask import TodoistAddTaskPage
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

def main():
    desired_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "appium:appPackage": "com.todoist",
        "appium:appActivity": "com.todoist.activity.HomeActivity",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
        }

    capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_caps)

    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', options=capabilities_options)

    try:
        add_task_page = TodoistAddTaskPage(driver)

        # Melakukan fungsi tambah task/jadwal
        add_task_page.add_task("tes jadwal", "tes deskripsi")
        print("Task added successfully")

    finally:
        print("berhasil")
```

TestLogin.py

```
from AppiumFramework.Pages.LoginPage import TodoistLoginPage
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

def main():
    desired_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "appium:appPackage": "com.todoist",
        "appium:appActivity": "com.todoist.activity.HomeActivity",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
        }

    capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_caps)

    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', options=capabilities_options)

    try:
        login_page = TodoistLoginPage(driver)

        # Melakukan login halaman
        login_page.click_sign_in_option()
        login_page.click_email_sign_in_button()
        login_page.input_email("myemail")
        login_page.input_password("mypassword")
        login_page.click_login_button()
        print("Login successful!")

        return driver  # Return the driver instance after logging in

    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

TestAddTask.py

```
from AppiumFramework.Pages.AddTask import TodoistAddTaskPage
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

def main():
    desired_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "appium:appPackage": "com.todoist",
        "appium:appActivity": "com.todoist.activity.HomeActivity",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
        }

    capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_caps)

    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', options=capabilities_options)

    try:
        add_task_page = TodoistAddTaskPage(driver)

        # Melakukan fungsi tambah task/jadwal
        add_task_page.add_task("tes jadwal", "tes deskripsi")
        print("Task added successfully")

    finally:
        print("berhasil")
```

Is there any recommended way to make the app keep opened after login and continues the test case to add task?